# How to alter the text of the post "Excerpt" box label in WordPress post editor?

Tags: theme-development, jquery

My theme gives the site owner the option of using each post's "Excerpt" field to fill in the "meta description" tag for each page.

It would be helpful if I can filter the text label and description text that appears on the default Excerpt input control when viewed inside the post editor.

Does a filter or hook exist for this?

Alternately, I suppose I could use jQuery to do something via the DOM.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

there is a filter hook you can use and it is `gettext`
here:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'wpse22764_gettext', 10, 2 );
function wpse22764_gettext( $translation, $original )
{
    if ( 'Excerpt' == $original ) {
        return 'My Excerpt label';
    }else{
        $pos = strpos($original, 'Excerpts are optional hand-crafted summaries of your');
        if ($pos !== false) {
            return  'My Excerpt description';
        }
    }
    return $translation;
}
```

Comment: Can I do the same for the "Tags" box?

Comment: yep, same filter hook

Answer (score 3):

if anyone trying to add for a specific post type you can try this code

```
add_filter('gettext', 'wp_video_link_excerpt_rename', 10, 2);
function wp_video_link_excerpt_rename($translation, $original)
{
    if (get_post_type( ) == 'video_link') {
        if ('Excerpt' == $original) {
            return 'Add Video Link';
        } else {
            $pos = strpos($original, 'Excerpts are optional hand-crafted summaries of your');
            if ($pos !== false) {
                return  'Add any video link in the box above';
            }
        }
    }
    return $translation;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I used the original answer and modified it to handle different post types:

```
// Customise the Excerpt field title and description via WP translation.
// Change the $post_types array to change the default Excerpt metabox title and description. The description is generic but substitutes the post_type to make it specific to the current post type.

add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_excerpt_info', 10, 2 );

function change_excerpt_info ( $translation, $original ) {
    $post_types = array( "service", "workshop", 'team' );
    $post = get_post( $post );
    $posttype = '';
    if ( $post ) {
        $posttype =  $post->post_type;
    }
    if ( in_array($posttype, $post_types) ) {
        if ( 'Excerpt' == $original ) {
             return ucfirst($posttype) . ' Teaser'; // Will appear as Service Teaser, Team Teaser, etc.
        } else $pos = strpos($original, 'Excerpts are optional hand-crafted summaries');
        if ($pos !== false) {
            // The Summary will incorporate the post_type into the description.
            $summary = 'This field will be displayed as a teaser or summary of anywhere this ' . $posttype . ' appears in a grid layout. You should always write a teaser of about 30 words. It will never be displayed on the actual ' . $posttype . ' page, so you can repeat content from other fields on this editing screen if you want.';
              return $summary;
        }
    }
    return $translation;
}
```